# Progress bar doesn't animate or appear

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar, progress

I am new to Bootstrap. I downloaded two themes related to resume. One theme had progress bar and the other dint. So I copied the code from this and pasted into the other index file. The progress bar appears but it is empty and doesn't animate. Please help me I am stuck. I have copied and pasted CSS code too.
Below is the code which I copied and pasted into other theme:

```
<!-- Skills Section -->
<section id="skills" class="skills-section section-padding">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="section-title wow fadeInUp">Skills</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="skill-progress">
          <div class="skill-title"><h3>UX Design</h3></div> 
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ><span>95%</span>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.progress -->
        </div><!-- /.skill-progress -->
        <div class="skill-progress">
          <div class="skill-title"><h3>Visual Design</h3></div> 
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ><span>80%</span>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.progress -->
        </div><!-- /.skill-progress -->
        <div class="skill-progress">
          <div class="skill-title"><h3>Business Design</h3></div>  
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ><span>75%</span>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.progress -->
        </div><!-- /.skill-progress -->
      </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="skill-progress">
          <div class="skill-title"><h3>Branding Design</h3></div> 
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ><span>95%</span>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.progress -->
        </div><!-- /.skill-progress -->
        <div class="skill-progress">
          <div class="skill-title"><h3>Motion Graphic</h3></div> 
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ><span>80%</span>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.progress -->
        </div><!-- /.skill-progress -->
        <div class="skill-progress">
          <div class="skill-title"><h3>Flyers Designing</h3></div>  
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ><span>75%</span>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.progress -->
        </div><!-- /.skill-progress -->
      </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

    <div class="skill-chart text-center">
      <h3>More skills</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row more-skill text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="chart" data-percent="91" data-color="e74c3c">
                <span class="percent"></span>
                <div class="chart-text">
                  <span>leadership</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="chart" data-percent="23" data-color="2ecc71">
                <span class="percent"></span>
                <div class="chart-text">
                  <span>Creativity</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="chart" data-percent="68" data-color="3498db">
                <span class="percent"></span>
                <div class="chart-text">
                  <span>Management</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="chart" data-percent="68" data-color="3498db">
                <span class="percent"></span>
                <div class="chart-text">
                  <span>Branding</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="chart" data-percent="68" data-color="3498db">
                <span class="percent"></span>
                <div class="chart-text">
                  <span>Marketing</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="chart" data-percent="68" data-color="3498db">
                <span class="percent"></span>
                <div class="chart-text">
                  <span>Motivation</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->
</section><!-- End Skills Section -->
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add what version of bootstrap you are using - 3 and 4 use sometimes similar syntax so it's hard to tell them apart from a snippet of HTML.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap you are using? Looking at both documentations of Bootstrap 3 and 4, both of them have different ways to achieve animation in the progress bars.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v3. When I copied the code from one theme to other, what all do I have to copy? CSS and Jquery too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation (growing of the line, in bootstrap 3 at least, worked something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.progress-bar').each(function() { // loops through all bars
    var percent_fill = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow') + '%'; // grabs the % from your html aria-valuenow attribute.               
    $(this).animate({ width: percent_fill }, { duration: 2000 }); //animates. Here is where you could pass additional easing function if desired with the help of jquery ui
  });
});
```

Now that we narrowed down on Bootstrap 3, you need to loop through your progress bars and assign the value to each, instead of the 80% I hardcoded. You need jQuery, which you have if the code above worked. If you want to use fancy easing/animation function you might need jQuery UI too. But you don't right now.

I have modified the above snipper to work on your example.

Comment: The code works and finally I could get the animation. But all of my skills progress bars are 80%. Can u tell me the code to make it as per my needs?
And the same happens with my pichart. Could you tell me the code to animate my picharts as well?

Comment: The snippet doesn't seem to work - there is a JavaScript error.

Comment: Sure, the snippet doesn't include Jquery, which it needs to run. But it works just fine with his html, if you include the jQuery library and bootstrap css.https://jsfiddle.net/70bstq8x/1/

Comment: I think you can do most things jsfiddle can do inside stackoverflow snippets now, including jQuery and bootstrap. +1 for a working demo nonetheless